# Pass DatePicker.Value of one form to another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

i have a login form that accepts an admin and ordinary users.

when an admin logs-in, his form has two DateTimePickers.

the first DateTimePicker allows the admin to choose a date that will serve as a minimum date = MinDate.

the second DateTimePicker allows the admin to choose a date that will serve as a maximum date = MaxDate.

click ok and both MinDate and MaxDate should be saved even when the application exited.

now, if an ordinary user logs-in his form has one DateTimePicker which allows him to choose a date. however, that DateTimePicker has a limited range defined by the MinDate and MaxDate from the admin form.

i have seen tutorials do this but they only use text/strings which are easy to manipulate.
please help... sorry if there's no "try" code here, i just cant do it.

Comment: So, is your real question "How do I convert the value from a DateTimePicker into something I can easily manipulate, and back again"?

Answer (score 1):

You should save the values the Admin provides in a database.

When the non-admin user visits the form, you will use the values in the database to set the minimum and maximum dates.

Then when the OK or Save button is pressed you validate the values against the values stored in the database.

Comment: i already thought of that but what i need is a sample code...thank you

Comment: what i mean is the syntax and what datatype my field should be on my database

Comment: Not to sound rude, but if you are unable to create a table, save something to it and retrieve it later, I suggest you read up on a beginners book on database programming.

Comment: i can do that...but my problem is what kind of datatype i must convert the datetimepicker.value to in order for the database to accept it.. because in sql you must specify the datatype for each field

Comment: Well, you should use `datetime` for the data type or even `date` would do from your database side. Use DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker.value); from your C# application.